# Using java regex how to find particular word any where in the string?

Tags: java, regex, string

Using java regex how  to find particular word anywhere in the string. My need is to check whether the string "Google" contains the word "gooe" or not.
For example:-

String: Goolge

word to find : gooe

The string "Google" contains all the characters g,o,o,e then it should return true.
IF the string is "wikipedia" and my word to find is "gooe" then it should return false.
How to form regex expression in this scenario..?

Comment: Per letter build a positive lookahead construct.

Comment: Are you sure you want to use regular expressions for this?

Comment: yes i want to use regular expression, because i want to use this regular expression in apache nifi.

Comment: Would `"ego"` "contain" `"gooe"`? i.e. does order and frequency of characters matter?

Comment: If you want to use regex, then use @revo's suggestion. Per letter positive lookahead. A simpler and more readable solution would be to use 2 loops

Comment: If the order of the characters matters, just insert `\p{L}*` (or `\w*`) in between the find word chars. See  [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NZaxsR/1) or [this Java demo](http://ideone.com/P2rt6A).

Comment: @revo what is per letter positive lookahead...?Any referrence links

Comment: @revo Your comment would be more profitable if turned into an answer.

Comment: i have a little messy solution which works with input :Google , GOOGLE , google gooosddle ,goooooooooooosddleeeeeeeee (these must match ?) . or  can you give some more example of your valid input or invalid (if there's any exceptional case )

Comment: You might be interested in reading those 2 source: http://ntz-develop.blogspot.com/2011/03/fuzzy-string-search.html?_sm_au_=ivV74KV3mKJ2Qkr7 https://itssmee.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/java-example-of-n-gram/

Comment: I have written some [javascript code](https://jsfiddle.net/1hmpsq8n/)  which solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find word in whole string you can use:

```
 "^(?=.*e)(?=.*o.*o)(?=.*g).*"
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not exactly match to my scenario. If my string is "looge" then your expression returns false. But my requirement is it should return true if my string  looge, google, elgoog etc.

Comment: Why it should return true when your string is "loogle" and you want to find "gooe"?

Comment: Thanks, but it is not exactly match to my scenario. If my string is "looge" then your expression returns false. But my requirement is it should return true if my string  looge, google, elgoog etc. My regex have to check the given word's characters whether present in the given string or not(it may be in any order). If it exist then it should return true. 
word to find gooe
String google,elgoog,looge,oogle for these strings my regex have to return true.
wiki, gold,lodge, for these string my regex have to return false.

Comment: Ok, now I see, you want to check if particular string contains all given chars.

Comment: I changed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested such RegEx that makes a use of "look-ahead":

```
(?=^.*g)(?=^.*o)(?=^.*e)
```

It should return true for all strings that contain g, o and e, while returning false if any of these characters is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build a positive lookahead for each letter. In case of having `gooe` as search term our RegEx would be:

```
(?i)(?=.*g)(?=.*o)(?=.*o)(?=.*e)
```

It's obvious that we have two exact same lookaheads. They will satisfy at the position of second `o` letter, so one is redundant. You can remove duplicate letters from search term before building final pattern. `(?i)` sets case-insensitivity flag on.

```
String term = "Gooe";   // Search term
String word = "google"; // Against word `Google`

String pattern = "(?i)(?=.*" + String.join(")(?=.*", term.split("(?!^)")) + ")";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher match = regex.matcher(word);
if (match.find()) {
    // Matched
}
```

See [demo here](https://ideone.com/K2LKn3)

If order is important and while looking for two `o`s, exactly both of them should exist then our RegEx would be:

```
(?i).*?g.*?o.*?o.*?e
```

Java:

```
String pattern = "(?i).*?" + String.join(".*?", term.split("(?!^)"));
```